# Android Youtube API crashes on Kitkat devices

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to play this video ID **I1iEFV1ZWHg** on YouTubePlayerView using Youtube sample application

I noticed that this video starts with promoted ad that requires custom toast,

this the crash message:

> Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line
>
> ## 3: Error inflating class com.google.android.libraries.youtube.common.ui.YouTubeTextView
>
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag
>
> Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Didn't find class
> "com.google.android.libraries.youtube.common.ui.YouTubeTextView" on
> path:

Comment: I'm having the same problem... did you fix it?

Comment: @AndrewAziz Did you got the solution for this?